# F# type constraints for vector operations

Tags: generics, f#, linear-algebra, generic-constraints

I'd like to write some generic functions and types in F# to work with vectors.  I have multiple different data types with static `(+)` and `(*)` operators so I can add them and multiply them by scalars (`float`s for now).

For instance, I've successfully got a `Vec2` class built where I can write

```
let v = 3.0 * Vec2(1.,1.) + Vec2(3.,4.)
```

Let's say I also have a `Vec3` or any other type of vector.  Here are two examples (pseudocode) of what I'd like to write:

### A generic function on vectors

I think this is possible with statically resolved type constraints that assert `'V` has a `(+)` and `(*)` but I can't get it to work.  It would be nice if I could name my type constraint as follows.

```
let average<'V when 'V : vector> (v1:'V) (v2:'V) =
    0.5 * (v1 + v2)
```

Is there an alternative that actually works?

### A generic type which is itself a vector type

For any type `'T` and a type `'V` representing a vector, we can add and scalar-multiply functions `'T -> 'V` like vectors.  I want to build a type like

```
type VecFunc<'T,'V when 'V : vector> = ...
```

As a simple example, `f : VecFunc<int,Vec2>` could store a function taking an `int` `x` and returning a `Vec2` with both components equal to `float x`.  Maybe we could evaluate the underlying function by calling an `Eval` method:

```
f.Eval(3) // would return Vec2(3.,3.)
```

I'd like to treat `VecFunc<int,Vec2>` as a vector type, giving it `(+)` and `(*)` operations so I can compute

```
(-2.0 * f + f).Eval(2) // returns Vec2(-4., -4.)
```

or combining it with the first example:

```
(average f g).Eval(1) // ...
```

Is there any way to use F# interfaces or type parameters to achieve these results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something along those lines by requiring that your vector types (and also functions on vectors) implement certain operators. Based on your example, I suppose you already have `+` for `Vec2` and `*` for multiplication of a vector by scalar. You can write the `average` function in terms of those operators and then it will work on any type that has those operators.

The only issue is that F# treats `*` in a somewhat special way and so you cannot easily do this if you have `*` of type `float * vector -> vector`. It seems to be working fine if you use `.*` for scalar by vector multiplication (and similarly, you can add `*.` for the other direction).

Here are my definitions of `Vec2` and `Vec3` with those operators:

```
type Vec2(a:float, b:float) = 
  member x.A = a
  member x.B = b
  static member (.*) (a:float, v:Vec2) = 
    Vec2(a*v.A, a*v.B)
  static member (+) (v1:Vec2, v2:Vec2) = 
    Vec2(v1.A+v2.A, v1.B+v2.B)

type Vec3(a:float, b:float, c:float) = 
  member x.A = a
  member x.B = b
  member x.C = c
  static member (.*) (a:float, v:Vec3) = 
    Vec3(a*v.A, a*v.B, a*v.C)
  static member (+) (v1:Vec3, v2:Vec3) = 
    Vec3(v1.A+v2.A, v1.B+v2.B, v1.C+v2.C)
```

Now you can write `average` as an inline function that uses static member constraints:

```
let inline average (v1:^V) (v2:^V) =
  (^V : (static member (.*) : float * ^V -> ^V) (0.5, v1 + v2))

average (Vec2(1.,1.)) (Vec2(3.,4.))
average (Vec3(1.,1.,1.)) (Vec3(3.,4.,5.))
```

F# automatically adds a constraint if you use the `+` operator, so I can just write `v1 + v2`. The `.*` operator is non-standard and so I had to invoke it explicitly.

For the second part of your question - as you noted, F# types cannot be parameterized by other types with static type constraints, so doing this requires some more tricks. One option you have is to add the operations that you need as parameters of the type and then have an `inline` function that captures the operations and passes them as regular functions to your `VecFunc` type. Here is an example:

```
type VecFunc<'T1, 'T2>(f:'T1 -> 'T2, mult:float * 'T1 -> 'T1, add:'T2 * 'T2 -> 'T2) = 
  member x.F = f
  member x.Mult = mult
  member x.Add = add
  static member (.*) (a:float, f:VecFunc<_, _>) = 
    VecFunc((fun v -> f.F (f.Mult(a, v))), f.Mult, f.Add)
  static member (+) (f1:VecFunc<_, _>, f2:VecFunc<_, _>) = 
    VecFunc((fun v -> f1.Add(f1.F v, f2.F v)), f1.Mult, f1.Add)

let inline vfunc (f:^V -> ^T) = 
    VecFunc< ^V, ^T>(f, 
      (fun (a, b) -> (^V : (static member (.*) : float * ^V -> ^V) (a, b))),
      (fun (a, b) -> a + b))

let vf = vfunc (fun (v:Vec2) -> v + v)
average vf vf
```

This type-checks, but I'm not exactly sure if it does the right thing (I'm not sure what addition and multiplication of vector functions should do!) - but in any case, it might help you find the right direction.

Comment: Thanks!  After further research, it looks like F# types don't accept statically resolved constraints on type parameters, so I am not optimistic.

Comment: No, they don't - but you can capture the operations insinde `inline` function and then pass them as regular functions to your generic type. I edited the answer to add an example (probably wrong, but should illustrate the idea).